# ODOO 14, How to render another template by rest api in a template?

Tags: python, odoo, qweb, odoo-14

I would like render a component in website.

```
<template>
    <% like to call a rest api which can render a template%>
</template>
```

I try as below

```
<t t-call=“/merchants” />
```

But it fails.
Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo template rendering doesn't work like that. Yes you can use `t-call` derivative but only to render another template within the rendering of current template. But that's not what you are looking for, probably you are looking for getting some data from the rest api and use that data to render the template, in that case what you have to do is within the python function responsible for rendering the qweb template, you have to get the rest api data (may be using `requests`) and pass that json data to the template rendering context, and use that data from context inside the template xml code.